# Mailchimp RSS feed for Wordpress site includes only new items, FEEDITEM-based feed has older items

Tags: wordpress, rss, mailchimp

I am trying to create a Mailchimp campaign email that includes two sections, one with the latest items from our news feed and one with the latest items from our events feed. Our site is Wordpress-based.

When I create an email with a single RSS feed from the news items using an RSS-based campaign, I get the most recent items, with the newest items first.

When I create an email with a regular campaign and use FEEDITEMS to display the news items, I two older items at the top, followed by the newer items. These items are also what I see if I go to [our url]/news/feed/

So (1) why would my Wordpress feed have older items at the top and (2) why is the RSS-based campaign correcting this issue, while the FEEDITEMS isn't?

Comment: So, it turns out that the two older posts are "sticky posts". But that still doesn't explain why Mailchimp is handling this feed differently for FEEDITEMS

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid the question would have been better in the WebApps section.

As you noticed, yoou cannot create an RSS campaign feeded by more than oone feed. And it's impossible to build valuable multiRSS campaigns with FEEDITEMS or other tags. 
Have a look to https://fliprss.com/ (in beta, not free) wich act as an overcoat of Mailchimp and solve the problem.

Comment: I was able to do it using a "Regular" campaign (not an RSS-based) with two FEEDITEM sections, its just that my sticky post appeared in my FEEDITEM-based feed but not my RSS feed campaign.

Looking at WebApps, I realize that it would have been more appropriate, but I didn't know it existed (and neither do a lot of people, apparently, it doesn't get very much traffic).